# Spring Boot Application with additional main() methods

Tags: spring-boot

I have a simple SpringBootApplication that sets up JPA and defines some Beans.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AnalysisApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AnalysisApplication.class, args);
}

@Autowired
SoftwareArchiveRepository swaRepository;

@Bean
SoftwareArchiveService swaService() {
    return new SoftwareArchiveService(swaRepository);
}

@Bean
PlatformService platformService(@Autowired PlatformRepository platformRepository) {
    return new JpaPlatformService(platformRepository);
}
// More Bean definitions omitted
}
```

I now want to use this context in a couple of classes that perform one time setup for my application that I will call manually. Although they use the defined beans, they are not really part of the application  - basically I want to perform a one-off data load exercise.

```
public class DatabaseLoader {

ApplicationContext context;

public static void main(String[] args) {

  DatabaseLoader loader = new DatabaseLoader();
  loader.run();

}

private void run() {

  context = ??????
  PlatformService service = context.getBean("platformService");
  // etc etc
}
```

What do I need to do to intialize a SpringBootApplication context so that all the SpringBoot autoconfiguration happens without actually calling SpringApplication.run(AnalysisApplication.class, args);

Comment: The `CommandLineRunner` interface doesn't do the trick?

Comment: As I understand it, the CommandLineRunner runs every time the Application is started/re-booted. I want a one-off, one-time only dataload that uses the initialised SpringBoot context

Comment: How do you want to initialize the application context without starting the application?